# Prove that $(n!)! > n[(n-1)!]^{n!}$

Tags: number-theory

> Prove that for a natural number $n > 2$, $$(n!)! > n[(n-1)!]^{n!}.$$

I thought about proving it by induction but was wondering if there was an easier way.

Comment: Easier, not sure. Give me a couple of hours to work around.

Comment: Let $n!=m$. You want to show that $$m!>\left(\frac{m}{n}\right)^m n$$ this somehow resembles to the Stirling formula. Not sure though

Answer (score 1):

Rewriting  the expression, you want to show that $$(n!)! > n \left(\frac{n!}{n}\right)^{n!}$$ or $$\frac{\left(\frac{n!}{n}\right)^{-n!} (n!)!}{n}>1\implies \log \left(\frac{\left(\frac{n!}{n}\right)^{-n!} (n!)!}{n}\right)>0$$ The only thing I have been able to do is a Taylor expansion around $n=2$; for the lhs, this gives $$2 (\gamma -1)^2 (n-2)+\left(-6+7 \gamma -\gamma ^3+\frac{1}{6} (\gamma -1) (2
   \gamma -5) \pi ^2\right) (n-2)^2+O\left((n-2)^3\right)$$ in which all coefficients are positive. Expanding to $O\left((n-2)^4\right)$, the coefficients becomes a monster (which I shall not write) which is again positive. Pushing the calculation to $O\left((n-2)^{10}\right)$ still show only positive coefficients  which are smaller and smaller.

But I am afraid that this does not prove anything.

I also tried $$u_n=\frac{((n-1)!)^{-n!} (n!)!}{n}$$ and used Taylor expansion for $$\log \left(\frac{u_{n+1}}{u_n}\right)=\log \left(\frac{15}{4}\right)+(n-2) \left(\frac{937}{60}-11 \log (2)+\gamma 
   \left(-\frac{157}{10}+4 \gamma +\log (64)\right)\right)+O\left((n-2)^2\right)$$ where again all terms are positive as well as in higher order expansions.

I have not been able to do anything for infinitely large values of $n$ using Stirling like formaulae.

May I confess that I am not happy at all with this answer ?

Comment: I feel there is something wrong with my answer too. It looked too easy

Comment: $$
\left(n!\right)! - n\left[\left(n-1\right)!\right]^{\, n!} =
\left\{\begin{array}{rclrcl}
0 & \mbox{if} & n & = & 2
\\
528 & \mbox{if} & n & = & 3
\\
620429448207886152892416 & \mbox{if} & n & = & 4
\\
6.6895 \times 10^{198} & \mbox{if} & n & = & 5
\end{array}\right.
$$

Answer (score 1):

$\newcommand{\bbx}[1]{\,\bbox[8px,border:1px groove navy]{{#1}}\,}
 \newcommand{\braces}[1]{\left\lbrace\,{#1}\,\right\rbrace}
 \newcommand{\bracks}[1]{\left\lbrack\,{#1}\,\right\rbrack}
 \newcommand{\dd}{\mathrm{d}}
 \newcommand{\ds}[1]{\displaystyle{#1}}
 \newcommand{\expo}[1]{\,\mathrm{e}^{#1}\,}
 \newcommand{\ic}{\mathrm{i}}
 \newcommand{\mc}[1]{\mathcal{#1}}
 \newcommand{\mrm}[1]{\mathrm{#1}}
 \newcommand{\pars}[1]{\left(\,{#1}\,\right)}
 \newcommand{\partiald}[3][]{\frac{\partial^{#1} #2}{\partial #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\root}[2][]{\,\sqrt[#1]{\,{#2}\,}\,}
 \newcommand{\totald}[3][]{\frac{\mathrm{d}^{#1} #2}{\mathrm{d} #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\verts}[1]{\left\vert\,{#1}\,\right\vert}$

> $\ds{\pars{n!}! > n\bracks{\pars{n - 1}!}^{\, n!}:\ ?.\qquad n = 3,4,5,\ldots}$

Note that it's equivalent to prove
$\ds{\quad\pars{n!}! > {\pars{n!}^{\, n!} \over n^{n! - 1}}\quad}$ or/and
$$
{m^{m} \over m!} < n^{m - 1}\quad\ \mbox{with}\quad m\ \equiv n!
$$.
For $\ds{\color{#f00}{n = 3}}$ it is obviously true because
$$
m = 3! = 6 \implies
\pars{~{m^{m} \over m!} = {6^{6} \over 6!} = {324 \over 5} < n^{m - 1} = 3^{5} = 243~}
$$

---

Then, we can concentrate in the case $\ds{\color{#f00}{n \geq 4}}$:
\begin{align}
{m^{m} \over m!} < \sum_{k = 0}^{\infty}{m^{k} \over k!} = \expo{m} =
\bracks{\expo{}\,\pars{\expo{} \over n}^{m - 1}}n^{m - 1}
\end{align}
The factor $\ds{\expo{}\,\pars{\expo{} \over n}^{m - 1} < 1}$ for
$\ds{\color{#f00}{n \geq 4}}$ which
$\underline{can\ be\ proved\ by\ induction}$:

- $\ds{\left.\expo{}\pars{\expo{} \over n}^{n! - 1}\right\vert_{\ n\ =\ 4} =
  \expo{}\pars{\expo{} \over 4}^{23} \approx 3.7643 \times 10^{-4} < 1}$
  $$\mbox{}$$
- $\ds{%
  \expo{}\,\pars{\expo{} \over n + 1}^{\pars{n + 1}! - 1}  <
  \expo{}\,\pars{\expo{} \over n}^{\pars{n + 1}! - 1} =
  \pars{\expo{} \over n}^{n\pars{n!}}
  \bracks{\expo{}\,\pars{\expo{} \over n}^{n! - 1}} \color{#f00}{< 1}}$

  > This finishes the proof.

Answer (score 0):

First note that for $m>2$:
$$m!>\left(\frac{m}{e}\right)^m\sqrt{2\pi m}$$
We first show that if $k>e$ and $n>2$ then
$$(n-1)\ln k>n-\frac{1}{2}\ln n-\ln\sqrt{2\pi}$$
which doesn't seem hard since $\ln\sqrt{2\pi}\approx0.92$. Now from this inequality we can see that:
$$n(\ln k-1)>\ln k-\ln\sqrt{2\pi n}\implies \left(\frac{k}{e}\right)^n>\frac{k}{\sqrt{2\pi n}}$$
So if $k>e$ then it is safe to say that
$$\left(\frac{m}{e}\right)^m\sqrt{2\pi m}>\left(\frac{m}{k}\right)^m k$$
for $m>2$. Back to the original question, let $n!=m$, you need to show
$$m!>\left(\frac{m}{n}\right)^m n$$
which shouldn't cause any trouble now.